# Electronic inside Spike Ultrasonic Sensor 45604

Tags: mindstorms, electronics, powered-up, disassembly, spike-prime

What is inside the Spike Ultrasonic Sensor 45604?

[image: Element photo]

Pictures of Top&Bottom PCB-Assembly would be helpful.

PoweredUp Cable and Connector use 6-Pin, but why is there used 8-Pin connector inside "black-and-white" Module connection? Are these 2 additional pins in use? What is their function?

Answer (score 4):

The back of this sensor unscrews. The back breaks out the 6-pin cable into an 8-pin connector:

[image: Inside of back]

The order of the connections for the pins in that picture from left to right are:

```
 6    5    4    3    x    x    2    1
ID2  ID1  VCC  GND   x    x   M2   M1
```

The primary sensor can be pulled out of the front of the part:

[image: Sensor Front]

We can then remove the shroud around the sensor to reveal the front side of the PCB:

[image: PCB Front]

The largest chip on the front side is an [STM8S105K6](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm8s105k6.html).

Here's the PCB from the back:

[image: PCB Back]

The largest chip on the back is a [HEF4049BT hex inverting buffer](https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/logic/buffers-inverters-transceivers/buffers/HEF4049BT.html).

I don't have any insight into why an 8-pin connector is used internally when there are only 6 conductors in the wire, but I did confirm electrically that 6 of the 8 pins are connected to the 6 conductors in the wire.

There are [3rd-party breakout boards](http://www.mindsensors.com/spike-prime/218-breadboard-connector-kit-for-spike-prime-ultrasonic-sensor-cable) that can make the connections from the back of the ultrasonic sensor available for advanced usage:

[image: Breakout board]

A header (or individual wires) of appropriate size can also be inserted directly into the back of the sensor without a specialized board, but the pitch is smaller (0.050" or 1.27mm) than what is typically used by hobbyists.

Comment: I'm confused/intrigued by https://community.legoeducation.com/blogs/31/220 , about "the back of the [distance] sensor can be removed and the cable detached, effectively becoming a LEGO Power Functions 2.0 (LPF2) breakout cable"

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks for sharing that! I've added info about that breakout board to the answer.

Comment: My guess for the 8-pin mystery is that it's a **fail-safe** mechanism. AFAICS, pins 3 and 4 are +VCC and GND, whereas 5 and 6 are not connected to anything. Since the connector is symmetrical, one could plug a connector rotated 180° - when doing so, +VCC and GND are connected to nothing, i.e. a fail-safe state. If this fail-safe was not in place, it could be possible to connect +VCC to GND and GND to +VCC (or some other weird combination) and potentially damage the circuits.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Can you confirm uC : STM8S105K6 in QFP on Top-Side ?
What is the SO16 Chip on Bottom Side ?
An Hex-CMOS Inverter as 9V Driver would be in SO14, so would not fit ... Jo

Comment: @user22626 I've added the info for those chips.

Comment: Pins 5 and 6 can also be multiplexed as UART. Pin 5 is TX and pin 6 is RX from the point of view of the hub.